# Excel Multiple If statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

Good Day,

Please let me know what is the mistake I made on this formula.

=IF(A6=TRUE,I6,0,IF(B6=TRUE,I6*1.2,I6))

basically what I want to do is, when **A6** is **true** then **J6 = I6** and if **B6** is also **true** the value on **J6** will be **I6*1.2** if not it will remain as **J6 = I6** .

Please see screenshot below
[image]

Comment: An `IF` statement only takes 2 a TRUE our false evaluation. Your second IF needs to be a separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=IF(A6=TRUE,I6,0)*IF(B6=TRUE,1.2,1)`
Or
`=IF(A6=False,0,IF(B6=TRUE,I6*1.2,I6))`

Comment: BRILLIANT. thank you very much! it works. so basically what I need to do is "Multiply" if the statement is true. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(A6=TRUE, IF((B6=TRUE),I6*1.2, I6),0)`

If `A6` is `TRUE` then we check if also `B6` is `TRUE` in the first `IF` condition. It's like this:

```
if(A6=TRUE)
{
    if(B6=TRUE)
    {
        I6*1.2
    }
    else
    {
        I6
    }
}
else
{
    0
}
```

Comment: Thank you for giving time on answering my query how ever it doesn't work. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(AND(A6=TRUE,B6=TRUE),I6*1.2,I6)
```

Comment: thanks for answering, however the if A6 is false J6 still keeps the value from I6.

Comment: What should happen if A6 is not true.. is it will be J6 = I6 ??